# Getting springframework FatalBeanException

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

Hi I am implemented Spring-xd framework and I have added xml configuration in my spring-module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int-aws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws"
    xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws/spring-integration-aws.xsd">
```

When I try to deploy this application I am getting below exception.

```
Deployment status for stream 'Stream3': DeploymentStatus
{state=failed,error(s)=org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [jar:file:/C:/spring-xd/xd/custom-modules/source/samplespringxd.jar!/config/spring-module.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.s
pringframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.f
actory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:138)
        at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:615)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
        at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:213)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.doDeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:217)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:200)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployModule(DeploymentListener.java:365)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployStreamModule(DeploymentListener.java:334)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.onChildAdded(DeploymentListener.java:181)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.childEvent(DeploymentListener.java:149)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.or
g/schema/context] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:128)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1422)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
        ... 30 more
```

Why I am getting this exception. What are the changes I need to do, to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a class loader issue. Perhaps you have put a `spring-context` jar in your module `/lib` directory; this will clash with XD's own spring jar. You should not put spring jars in your module's lib.